# What does "crank me up to nine" mean in this Seinfeld monologue?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, spoken-english

"crank me up to nine" is around 18~19s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aiFh4VR448

#### Full script:

> The cosmetic surgery procedures
>   that are available to people
>   today--
>   Liposuction,
>   are you familiar with this?
>   This is a fat-sucking machine.
>
> Now, you know, somewhere,
>   somebody is working on a way
>   that this thing
>   could go into a restaurant.
>   And you could just
>   order it off the menu:
>   "I'll tell you what.
>   Give me the cheesecake.
>   **crank me up to nine**,
>   and put a scoop of ice cream
>   on the side."

Answer (score 2):

Many machines have a knob that you can turn to change the power of the machine. Perhaps you are most familiar with the volume knob on a hi-fi system.  This knob is often marked 0-10  (though I have heard of some high-end guitar amps that go up to 11!)

"Crank" is a colourful way of saying "turn", so he is just saying "give me the cheesecake, ice cream and the liposuction machine, and turn the machine onto a high setting.  "Crank *me* up to 9" because he would be plugged into the machine. It also sounds like ordering food when people say, for example, "I'm the steak".

Comment: Doctor Who's sonic screwdriver goes up to 11, apparently.